# PHP/Wordpress: Capture OnClick Event 'Download URL; and Pass it To 'Thank You' Page for Initializing Download

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

In wordpress, I have a single.php page that features a download link to a file using an onclick event.

This is what my href looks like today:

```
 <a onclick="window.open('<?php echo $software_download_url; ?>');>DOWNLOAD</a>
```

I basically want a user to click on the DOWNLOAD link, then go to a 'Thank You' page where the file would begin downloading. But also, to grab the TITLE of that page and pass that too.

I envision the flow as capturing whatever is echoed in the onclick event, then pass it as a parameter in the url so the download can initialize.

So something like this:

```
 <a onclick="window.open('thank_you.php?dl=<?php echo $software_download_url; ?>?title=<?php echo $the_title;?>');>DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Unless there's a better way. But I'm not sure how to capture that file/title  as a parameter from url, then have the download initialize.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

To set and get parameters in the URL you need to use WordPress query vars.
For your own custom query var you need to first register it like this:

```
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = "title";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

This code goes in to your templates function.php or you can make a small plugin that adds it if you wish.

Then to get the query vars you use `get_query_var()` like this in your 'thank you' page's template:

```
$title = get_query_var('title', false);
```

You can read more about getting query vars here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var